# Referencing nested JSON Array

Tags: android, json

I am attempting to create a weather app using Yahoo's api.

Unfortunately, I don't know how to reference JSON, and although I have searched for solutions, they haven't been applicable to me.

I am attempting to retrieve the array called forecast in :

```
{
    "query": {
        "count": 1,
        "created": "2016-06-22T16:12:10Z",
        "lang": "en-US",
        "results": {
            "channel": {
                "units": {
                    "distance": "km",
                    "pressure": "mb",
                    "speed": "km/h",
                    "temperature": "C"
                },
                "title": "Yahoo! Weather - Sydney, NSW, AU",
                "link": "http://us.rd.yahoo.com/dailynews/rss/weather/Country__Country/*https://weather.yahoo.com/country/state/city-26198393/",
                "description": "Yahoo! Weather for Sydney, NSW, AU",
                "language": "en-us",
                "lastBuildDate": "Thu, 23 Jun 2016 02:12 AM AEST",
                "ttl": "60",
                "location": {
                    "city": "Sydney",
                    "country": "Australia",
                    "region": " NSW"
                },
                "wind": {
                    "chill": "48",
                    "direction": "293",
                    "speed": "17.70"
                },
                "atmosphere": {
                    "humidity": "72",
                    "pressure": "34202.54",
                    "rising": "0",
                    "visibility": "25.91"
                },
                "astronomy": {
                    "sunrise": "7:1 am",
                    "sunset": "4:55 pm"
                },
                "image": {
                    "title": "Yahoo! Weather",
                    "width": "142",
                    "height": "18",
                    "link": "http://weather.yahoo.com",
                    "url": "http://l.yimg.com/a/i/brand/purplelogo//uh/us/news-wea.gif"
                },
                "item": {
                    "title": "Conditions for Sydney, NSW, AU at 01:00 AM AEST",
                    "lat": "-33.868999",
                    "long": "151.209045",
                    "link": "http://us.rd.yahoo.com/dailynews/rss/weather/Country__Country/*https://weather.yahoo.com/country/state/city-26198393/",
                    "pubDate": "Thu, 23 Jun 2016 01:00 AM AEST",
                    "condition": {
                        "code": "31",
                        "date": "Thu, 23 Jun 2016 01:00 AM AEST",
                        "temp": "10",
                        "text": "Clear"
                    },
                    "forecast": [{
                        "code": "34",
                        "date": "23 Jun 2016",
                        "day": "Thu",
                        "high": "16",
                        "low": "10",
                        "text": "Mostly Sunny"
                    }, {
                        "code": "23",
                        "date": "24 Jun 2016",
                        "day": "Fri",
                        "high": "15",
                        "low": "10",
                        "text": "Breezy"
                    }, {
                        "code": "23",
                        "date": "25 Jun 2016",
                        "day": "Sat",
                        "high": "13",
                        "low": "8",
                        "text": "Breezy"
                    }, {
                        "code": "28",
                        "date": "26 Jun 2016",
                        "day": "Sun",
                        "high": "12",
                        "low": "6",
                        "text": "Mostly Cloudy"
                    }, {
                        "code": "11",
                        "date": "27 Jun 2016",
                        "day": "Mon",
                        "high": "10",
                        "low": "8",
                        "text": "Showers"
                    }, {
                        "code": "11",
                        "date": "28 Jun 2016",
                        "day": "Tue",
                        "high": "14",
                        "low": "10",
                        "text": "Showers"
                    }, {
                        "code": "30",
                        "date": "29 Jun 2016",
                        "day": "Wed",
                        "high": "15",
                        "low": "11",
                        "text": "Partly Cloudy"
                    }, {
                        "code": "34",
                        "date": "30 Jun 2016",
                        "day": "Thu",
                        "high": "16",
                        "low": "8",
                        "text": "Mostly Sunny"
                    }, {
                        "code": "34",
                        "date": "01 Jul 2016",
                        "day": "Fri",
                        "high": "16",
                        "low": "11",
                        "text": "Mostly Sunny"
                    }, {
                        "code": "23",
                        "date": "02 Jul 2016",
                        "day": "Sat",
                        "high": "12",
                        "low": "11",
                        "text": "Breezy"
                    }],
                    "description": "<![CDATA[<img src=\"http://l.yimg.com/a/i/us/we/52/31.gif\"/>\n<BR />\n<b>Current Conditions:</b>\n<BR />Clear\n<BR />\n<BR />\n<b>Forecast:</b>\n<BR /> Thu - Mostly Sunny. High: 16Low: 10\n<BR /> Fri - Breezy. High: 15Low: 10\n<BR /> Sat - Breezy. High: 13Low: 8\n<BR /> Sun - Mostly Cloudy. High: 12Low: 6\n<BR /> Mon - Showers. High: 10Low: 8\n<BR />\n<BR />\n<a href=\"http://us.rd.yahoo.com/dailynews/rss/weather/Country__Country/*https://weather.yahoo.com/country/state/city-26198393/\">Full Forecast at Yahoo! Weather</a>\n<BR />\n<BR />\n(provided by <a href=\"http://www.weather.com\" >The Weather Channel</a>)\n<BR />\n]]>",
                    "guid": {
                        "isPermaLink": "false"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried this solution:

```
final String OWM_QUERY = "query";
final String OWM_RESULTS = "results";
final String OWM_CHANNEL = "channel";
final String OWM_ITEM = "item";
final String OWM_FORECAST = "forecast";
final String OWM_MAX = "high";
final String OWM_MIN = "low";    

JSONObject forecastJson = new JSONObject(forecastJsonStr);
JSONArray weatherArray = forecastJson.getJSONObject(OWM_QUERY)
    .getJSONObject(OWM_RESULTS)
    .getJSONObject(OWM_CHANNEL)
    .getJSONObject(OWM_ITEM)
    .getJSONArray(OWM_FORECAST);
```

But this returns me a:

> Value null at results of type org.json.JSONObject$1 cannot be converted to JSONObject

Error, so I assume the way I am trying to reference the array is incorrect.

Thanks for any help in advance

EDIT:

Full Error:

```
06-23 03:02:27.570 18607-18710/com.example.alan.organiseme V/FetchWeatherTask: Forecast string: {"query":{"count":0,"created":"2016-06-22T17:02:08Z","lang":"en-US","results":null}}
06-23 03:02:27.571 18607-18710/com.example.alan.organiseme E/FetchWeatherTask: Value null at results of type org.json.JSONObject$1 cannot be converted to JSONObject
org.json.JSONException: Value null at results of type org.json.JSONObject$1 cannot be converted to JSONObject
   at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:100)
   at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONObject(JSONObject.java:613)
   at com.example.alan.organiseme.weather$FetchWeatherTask.getWeatherDataFromJson(weather.java:130)
   at com.example.alan.organiseme.weather$FetchWeatherTask.doInBackground(weather.java:274)
   at com.example.alan.organiseme.weather$FetchWeatherTask.doInBackground(weather.java:78)
   at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
   at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
06-23 03:02:27.571 18607-18710/com.example.alan.organiseme W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value null at results of type org.json.JSONObject$1 cannot be converted to JSONObject
06-23 03:02:27.571 18607-18710/com.example.alan.organiseme W/System.err:     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:100)
06-23 03:02:27.571 18607-18710/com.example.alan.organiseme W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONObject(JSONObject.java:613)
06-23 03:02:27.571 18607-18710/com.example.alan.organiseme W/System.err:     at com.example.alan.organiseme.weather$FetchWeatherTask.getWeatherDataFromJson(weather.java:130)
06-23 03:02:27.571 18607-18710/com.example.alan.organiseme W/System.err:     at com.example.alan.organiseme.weather$FetchWeatherTask.doInBackground(weather.java:274)
06-23 03:02:27.571 18607-18710/com.example.alan.organiseme W/System.err:     at com.example.alan.organiseme.weather$FetchWeatherTask.doInBackground(weather.java:78)
06-23 03:02:27.572 18607-18710/com.example.alan.organiseme W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
06-23 03:02:27.572 18607-18710/com.example.alan.organiseme W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
06-23 03:02:27.572 18607-18710/com.example.alan.organiseme W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
06-23 03:02:27.572 18607-18710/com.example.alan.organiseme W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
06-23 03:02:27.572 18607-18710/com.example.alan.organiseme W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
06-23 03:02:27.572 18607-18710/com.example.alan.organiseme W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Second Error

```
06-23 03:36:11.704 17086-17172/com.example.alan.organiseme V/FetchWeatherTask: Forecast string: {"query":{"count":1,"created":"2016-06-22T17:35:52Z","lang":"en-US","results":{"channel":{"units":{"distance":"km","pressure":"mb","speed":"km/h","temperature":"C"},"title":"Yahoo! Weather - Sydney, NSW, AU","link":"http://us.rd.yahoo.com/dailynews/rss/weather/Country__Country/*https://weather.yahoo.com/country/state/city-55857444/","description":"Yahoo! Weather for Sydney, NSW, AU","language":"en-us","lastBuildDate":"Thu, 23 Jun 2016 03:35 AM AEST","ttl":"60","location":{"city":"Sydney","country":"Australia","region":" NSW"},"wind":{"chill":"45","direction":"338","speed":"11.27"},"atmosphere":{"humidity":"80","pressure":"33965.49","rising":"0","visibility":"25.91"},"astronomy":{"sunrise":"7:1 am","sunset":"4:55 pm"},"image":{"title":"Yahoo! Weather","width":"142","height":"18","link":"http://weather.yahoo.com","url":"http://l.yimg.com/a/i/brand/purplelogo//uh/us/news-wea.gif"},"item":{"title":"Conditions for Sydney, NSW, AU at 03:00 AM AEST","lat":"-33.783611","long":"151.145325","link":"http://us.rd.yahoo.com/dailynews/rss/weather/Country__Country/*https://weather.yahoo.com/country/state/city-55857444/","pubDate":"Thu, 23 Jun 2016 03:00 AM AEST","condition":{"code":"31","date":"Thu, 23 Jun 2016 03:00 AM AEST","temp":"8","text":"Clear"},"forecast":[{"code":"30","date":"23 Jun 2016","day":"Thu","high":"15","low":"6","text":"Partly Cloudy"},{"code":"32","date":"24 Jun 2016","day":"Fri","high":"14","low":"7","text":"Sunny"},{"code":"32","date":"25 Jun 2016","day":"Sat","high":"12","low":"5","text":"Sunny"},{"code":"28","date":"26 Jun 2016","day":"Sun","high":"11","low":"3","text":"Mostly Cloudy"},{"code":"39","date":"27 Jun 2016","day":"Mon","high":"8","low":"6","text":"Scattered Showers"},{"code":"39","date":"28 Jun 2016","day":"Tue","high":"12","low":"6","text":"Scattered Showers"},{"code":"30","date":"29 Jun 2016","day":"Wed","high":"14","low":"7","text":"Partly Cloudy"},{"code":"34","date":"30 Jun 2016","day":"Thu","high":"15","low":"6","text":"Mostly Sunny"},{"code":"34","date":"01 Jul 2016","day":"Fri","high":"15","low":"8","text":"Mostly Sunny"},{"code":"34","date":"02 Jul 2016","day":"Sat","high":"12","low":"10","text":"Mostly Sunny"}],"description":"<![CDATA[<img src=\"http://l.yimg.com/a/i/us/we/52/31.gif\"/>\n<BR />\n<b>Current Conditions:</b>\n<BR />Clear\n<BR />\n<BR />\n<b>Forecast:</b>\n<BR /> Thu - Partly Cloudy. High: 15Low: 6\n<BR /> Fri - Sunny. High: 14Low: 7\n<BR /> Sat - Sunny. High: 12Low: 5\n<BR /> Sun - Mostly Cloudy. High: 11Low: 3\n<BR /> Mon - Scattered Showers. High: 8Low: 6\n<BR />\n<BR />\n<a href=\"http://us.rd.yahoo.com/dailynews/rss/weather/Country__Country/*https://weather.yahoo.com/country/state/city-55857444/\">Full Forecast at Yahoo! Weather</a>\n<BR />\n<BR />\n(provided by <a href=\"http://www.weather.com\" >The Weather Channel</a>)\n<BR />\n]]>","guid":{"isPermaLink":"false"}}}}}}
06-23 03:36:11.730 17086-17172/com.example.alan.organiseme E/FetchWeatherTask: No value for forecast
                                                                               org.json.JSONException: No value for forecast
                                                                                   at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:389)
                                                                                   at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONArray(JSONObject.java:584)
                                                                                   at com.example.alan.organiseme.weather$FetchWeatherTask.getWeatherDataFromJson(weather.java:168)
                                                                                   at com.example.alan.organiseme.weather$FetchWeatherTask.doInBackground(weather.java:274)
                                                                                   at com.example.alan.organiseme.weather$FetchWeatherTask.doInBackground(weather.java:78)
                                                                                   at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
                                                                                   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                                   at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
                                                                                   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
                                                                                   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
                                                                                   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
06-23 03:36:11.730 17086-17172/com.example.alan.organiseme W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: No value for forecast
06-23 03:36:11.730 17086-17172/com.example.alan.organiseme W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:389)
06-23 03:36:11.730 17086-17172/com.example.alan.organiseme W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONArray(JSONObject.java:584)
06-23 03:36:11.730 17086-17172/com.example.alan.organiseme W/System.err:     at com.example.alan.organiseme.weather$FetchWeatherTask.getWeatherDataFromJson(weather.java:168)
06-23 03:36:11.730 17086-17172/com.example.alan.organiseme W/System.err:     at com.example.alan.organiseme.weather$FetchWeatherTask.doInBackground(weather.java:274)
06-23 03:36:11.730 17086-17172/com.example.alan.organiseme W/System.err:     at com.example.alan.organiseme.weather$FetchWeatherTask.doInBackground(weather.java:78)
06-23 03:36:11.730 17086-17172/com.example.alan.organiseme W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
06-23 03:36:11.730 17086-17172/com.example.alan.organiseme W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
06-23 03:36:11.730 17086-17172/com.example.alan.organiseme W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
06-23 03:36:11.730 17086-17172/com.example.alan.organiseme W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
06-23 03:36:11.730 17086-17172/com.example.alan.organiseme W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
06-23 03:36:11.730 17086-17172/com.example.alan.organiseme W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: You may want to break up each `getJSONObject` method into individual steps and debug from there. Otherwise, please [edit] with the full error message because what you have looks fine as far as parsing the JSON goes.

Comment: Sorry about that, I added the full error.

Comment: Look at the top line of that error, `results:null`, so, that would mean somehow the API call is wrong.

Comment: You're right! I fixed the API call, cheers.

I still have an error, No value for forecast. But examining the imported JSON shows there is definitely an array.

I think there is still a problem with my parsing, I'm not too sure. I'll update with the new logs.

Comment: Is it maybe because the forecast nested Object might not be an array, I do notice things like description and another object called guid?

Is there a way to ignore the description and the other object and convert it into an array?

Comment: The forecast is definitely in that response... `query.results.channel.item.forecast` does return an array